# makefile to compile an executable in linux shell script

Tags: c++, linux, shell, makefile

Apologize in advance, I asked a similar question earlier but I didn't get a clear answer and I'm desperate since I've been trying to figure it out for 6 hours without a teacher and since my assignments due tonight I just can't take it any more. I have directory with just **one** file in it: "proj1.cpp" with a lot of code on it. I need to use a file 'makefile' in the same directory (it's named makefile), in order to "compile an executable called: proj1.x". (I *have* to do this in Linux by the way, through an SSH shell).

I'd really appreciate if someone could sort of walk me through step my step instructions how / why to do this for my situation and not just redirect me to a different page? I only ask because I know the solution is easy to an experienced programmer.

Comment: Please keep the language squeaky clean — this is a family show!  Why on earth would you need to create `proj1.x`?  That's not a conventional extension on Unix-like systems.  (There's bound to be some language that uses it for its source code, but executables are not given any extension by default.)  If you only need to create `proj1`, then you don't even need a makefile.  The easiest way to make `proj1.x` might be a one-line makefile: `proj1.x: proj1; ln -s proj1 proj1.x` (no tabs needed).

Comment: Sorry about the language lol. But thanks for the answer I think I'm finally getting it to work!!! Just got a little bit of tweaking to do. Also I don't know haha my professor required me to do it this way.

Comment: @TommyBoi have you looked at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)? It will greatly simplify your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the job very simply:

```
proj1.x: proj1.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -o $@ proj1.cpp
```

That's two lines of `makefile`.  There must be a <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the start of the second line.  The first line says that `proj1.x` depends on `proj1.cpp`; if `proj1.cpp` is newer than `proj1.x` (or `proj1.x` does not exist), then do the actions on the second line.  The second line runs the C++ compiler to produce `proj1.x` (that's the `$@`; you could write `proj1.x` there if you wanted to, though `$@` is better in the long run).  I'm assuming your `make` uses `${CXX}` for the C++ compiler, and `${CXXFLAGS}` for the compiler options.  If you need extra libraries, you can add those.  Etc.

That's a completely bare-bones `makefile`.  It will probably get you going.  (Incidentally, 188 lines of code is not a lot.)

---

Adding libraries:

```
LDFLAGS = -L …
LDLIBS  = -lxyz -lpqr

proj1.x: proj1.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -o $@ proj1.cpp ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

Note that many (probably most) people use the alternative `$(VAR)` notation in preference to `${VAR}`.  I prefer the curly brace notation, so that's what I use unless there's a coding standard to the contrary — but you've been informed of the alternative.

Note that source files and object files are listed before libraries unless you've got a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Alright cool I'm getting it to work. how do I include libraries in the makelist file? Is it the same way I do it in a regular c++ program?